# Trying to get information from database based query but determined by country (location)

Tags: php, sql

I am triyng to receive data with a query. The query could be in any of the columns in my database, however I only want to get the data if its from the same country. It is not working.

the url goes like this: search.php?query=econ&country=England

so the query is: "econ"
and the country is "england"

Anything that contains econ will be gathered IF it is also from england..

first I get the variables from the url

```
$searchQuery = $_GET['query'];
$searchCountry =  $_GET['country'];
```

here is my SQL

```
SELECT * from sbEvents 
WHERE EventCountry =    ?
AND  (Name         LIKE ?
OR    Description  LIKE ?
OR    Address      LIKE ?
OR    Author       LIKE ?)
```

then i populate it with

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sth);
$stmt->execute(array($searchCountry, $searchQuery, $searchQuery, $searchQuery, $searchQuery));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

then obviously i print it out into JSON. This works if i remove the country part (so its not something else that's going wrong) I believe it is juts my SQL structure, ie: and ( or LIKE ? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, like clause will need %string% around it.

```
$sq = "%$searchQuery%";
$stmt->execute(array($searchCountry, $sq, $sq, $sq, $sq));
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now. What exactly does encapsulating it in % do?

Comment: like clause often %. When it becomes $searchquery%, then will show data after string. %$searchquery, will show data before string.